# Is it possible to use OpenCL for PowerVR SGX530 GPU device?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

Is it possible to use OpenCL for PowerVR SGX530 GPU device?  I have to write image recognition software that can run on Droid X smartphone. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide links, references, citations, sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is, but it depends on the SOC vendor, have a look at this:

http://www.imgtec.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=194

Imagination Technologies say that the gpu has OpenCL 1.0 embedded capabilities, but it depends on the SOC vendor whether a driver is available or not

Comment: link above expired. Possibly this is the up-to-date one ? https://forums.imgtec.com/t/opencl-support/226/24

Answer (score 3):

I found that it is not possible to use OpenCL. I'd have to rewrite my algorithm to OpenGL and use shaders and vertexes - then I can gain "General Purpose" programming (welcome back to past, about 4-5 years back to be more exact).

Take a look at the following thread elaborates on what is possible and not possible to do up to date (14th of Nov,2010):
[link text](http://www.imgtec.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=194&PID=2609#2609)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this example from the folks from Nokia:

http://www.hotchips.org/archives/hc21/1_sun/HC21.23.2.OpenCLTutorial-Epub/HC21.23.270.Pulli-OpenCL-in-Handheld-Devices.pdf

So I ask myself, is there any SDK from any mobile platform/os out there that I could use to test some of my desktop apps to an embedded app? I'd really, really appreciate to be able to program opencl on mobile/tablets systems. Vertex/fragment shader are not much of help because their specs for embedded systems do not include all the extensions we would need to rewrite our opencl code to shader.